# MySQL multiple SELECT query with CASE WHEN, INNER JOIN and GROUP BY1

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, inner-join, case-when

I try to build a multiple select query with inner join and group by option afterwards and I do not really understand why my query does not work (I'm not familiar with SQL and php, maybe that's why). I get the error message that my syntax is wrong.

I have multiple tables with the same structure and I want to have some of the cases in one query grouped by one common variable.

The query is like that:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT Var1, 
    MAX( CASE WHEN Var2 ='2015' AND Var3='A1_U18' THEN Var4 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'A1_U18_0',
    MAX( CASE WHEN Var2 ='2015' AND Var3='A31_U6' THEN Var4 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'A31_U6_0'
    FROM table_a) AS a,

    (SELECT Var1,
    MAX( CASE WHEN Var2 ='2015' AND Var3='B21_U3' THEN Var4 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'B21_U3_0',
    MAX( CASE WHEN Var2 ='2015' AND Var3='B21_U6' THEN Var4 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'B21_U6_0'
    FROM table_b) AS b,

    (SELECT Var1,
    MAX( CASE WHEN Var2 ='2015' AND Var3='C21_U3' THEN Var4 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'C21_U3_0',
    MAX( CASE WHEN Var2 ='2015' AND Var3='C21_U6' THEN Var4 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'C21_U6_0'
    FROM table_c) AS c

INNER JOIN a b
    ON a.Var1 = b.Var1
INNER JOIN a c
    ON a.Var1 = c.Var1

GROUP BY a.Var1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: not sure what you want - maybe add sample data and expected results.  it looks like the MAX is totally unnecessary

Comment: For start you dont have `FROM a` anywhere. Also use better alias for tables  ...  `a,b,c` is very easy to confuse, specially when fields also are called `a,b,c`

Answer (score 1):

1. Your subquery cant return multiple fields
2. You miss include `FROM a`
3. To declare alias you need to use backquote '`' you are using single quote `'` and that is for string.

I highly recomend you do a basic mySql tutorial, **[This](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)** one help a lot

But You probably need something like this.

```
SELECT a.*, 
       b.`B21_U3_0`, b.`B21_U6_0`,
       c.`C21_U3_0`, c.`C21_U6_0`

FROM 
    (SELECT Var1, 
            MAX( CASE WHEN Var2 ='2015' AND Var3='A1_U18' 
                      THEN Var4 ELSE 0 END ) AS `A1_U18_0`,
            MAX( CASE WHEN Var2 ='2015' AND Var3='A31_U6' 
                      THEN Var4 ELSE 0 END ) AS `A31_U6_0`
     FROM table_a
     GROUP BY Var1
    ) AS a
JOIN    
    (SELECT Var1,
            MAX( CASE WHEN Var2 ='2015' AND Var3='B21_U3' 
                      THEN Var4 ELSE 0 END ) AS `B21_U3_0`,
            MAX( CASE WHEN Var2 ='2015' AND Var3='B21_U6' 
                      THEN Var4 ELSE 0 END ) AS `B21_U6_0`
     FROM table_b
     GROUP BY Var1 
    ) AS b
  ON a.Var1 = b.Var1
JOIN   
    (SELECT Var1,
           MAX( CASE WHEN Var2 ='2015' AND Var3='C21_U3' 
                     THEN Var4 ELSE 0 END ) AS `C21_U3_0`,
           MAX( CASE WHEN Var2 ='2015' AND Var3='C21_U6' 
                     THEN Var4 ELSE 0 END ) AS `C21_U6_0`
     FROM table_c
     GROUP BY Var1
    ) AS c
ON a.Var1 = c.Var1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice! For me it seems to be adequate, but when I try to use I get again a syntax error (near to c.`C21_U3_0`, c.`C21_U6_0`

FROM 
    (SELECT Var1, ...)
and when I change to punctuation then I get the sytnax error near to FROM 
    (SELECT Var1, 
            MAX( CASE WHEN Var2 ='2015'...).
Even if I try to repoduce it in [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all) I get the message "syntax error in FROm clause.

Comment: Again you need to start learning the basic. But try a single subquery first to test the syntaxis and keep adding or removing thing to find where is the error.

Comment: Ok, I miss one comma between the field, check now.

Comment: Everything fine! Great! Thanks! I have to care about the basics later, now it was urgent, but thanks for the link!